# Is there a way to customize nginx proxy in google flexible appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

We are trying to running an application (a java servlet that connects to guacamole server) on flexible appengine, in our troubleshooting it looks like there is a nginx proxy on the google cloud instance (the instance from which docker image is running).

Is there a way we customize the nginx configuration the google cloud instance to help resolve our issues?

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  The proxy is part of our infrastructure that you can't really customize.  Can you be a little more specific?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have the same request, my use case is my Docker app needs websockets via SockJS, and they are not working through the flexible proxy - the fixes suggested all require a configuration of the Nginx proxy

Comment: Sadly, you're not going to have much luck here :(. The load balancer doesn't support websockets, so even if you could enable this on the proxy it wouldn't work.  The good news is that we're actively working on websockets support :)

Comment: Have you guys finally found any way to edit nginx configuration on appengine?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hey @JustinBeckwith, I'd love to enable nginx's gzip compression on all relevant responses. It seems GAE Flex has this disabled (unlike GAE Standard)... Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, there's an actual good scenario :) sadly no way to turn that on just yet.  That's something we can add to the backlog though.

Comment: Update!  We enabled gzip by default on nginx, and it rolls out monday ;)

Comment: Can [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-custom-runtimes-samples/tree/master/nginx) be used?

Comment: Hello @JustinBeckwith I have a question regarding Nginx with GAE if you have some time can you please have a look, Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47486110/do-i-need-to-setup-a-reverse-proxy-behind-google-app-engine-or-not

Comment: @JustinBeckwith In my case, I'd like to block some path on Ngxinx, not on my node application. It still not possible to customize? I was able to do on aws-eb.