# Google App Engine Node JS: enable CORS and

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, google-app-engine, nginx

I'm having a CORS issue for 2 days now in Google App Engine and NGINX with an Express API:

`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Although I have configured [Express CORS module](https://github.com/expressjs/cors), I still get the error. Here's my config:

```
const app = express();
const corsWhiteList = [
  'https://mysite',
  'https://www.mysite',
  'http://localhost:4200'
];
const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (corsWhiteList.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by cors'));
    }
  },
  credentials: true,
  preflightContinue: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, 
  allowedHeader: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
```

I've also tried to set `router.use()`but it had no effect. 
I have set a `cors-config.json` file to my bucket with `gsutil`:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["https://mysite", "https://www.mysite"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
    "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

In my development environment, the CORS module works fine: if I update my CORS white list to a non matching one for instance. I even tried CORS's module basic config but had the same result: passing in development, failing in production.

Here's a screenshot of the request in dev and the error in prod:

[image: Dev successfull Access-Allow-Cross-Origin headers]

[image: Prod Allow-Origin headers error]

Another guess was to enable CORS in Nginx but [it appears that it's not configurable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853799/is-there-a-way-to-customize-nginx-proxy-in-google-flexible-appengine#answer-40881438)

**Question:**

- is Google App Engine suitable for deploying a Node API server ?
- Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue ? 
  Thanks

Comment: *“Status code: 502”* for the OPTIONS request, is what’s shown in the screenshot. That means “Bad Gateway” and indicates some complete internal failure somewhere on the server side that’s totally unrelated to your CORS config. It often means that some process on some other port isn’t up and listening at all (e.g., something that you’re proxying to). So you need to get on that server and look through server-side logs there and see what information the server is logging about the internal failure which causes the server to send that 502 response

Comment: Thanks for your comment @sideshowbarker, it's weird but I don't have any errors; i think i'll give Cloud Compute a try to be able to tune the infrastructure

Comment: @t3__rry Could you solve this problem? I just ran into the same issue.

Comment: Nope, I switched to Digital Ocean but a guy from Google's support told me that the issue could come from `pm2`as GAE does the same job... So CORS were not the issue...